# NoMethodError in Admin::DashboardController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

am new to rails, and am using active admin for a work, and i get this error whenever i open active admin dashboard

```
NoMethodError in Admin::DashboardController#index
undefined method `asideSection' for #<Admin::DashboardController:0x00007fc544017d70>
```

here is my application_conrtoller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :asideSection
    def hhome

    end

    def getAsideSection
        @asideSections = Page.all
    end
end
```

how can i fix it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`before_action :asideSection` tries to call a method named `asideSection`.

This method does not exist.

However, you *have* defined a method named: `getAsideSection`. I presume that this is what you want to be called.

So, you could either change that to: `before_action :getAsideSection`, or rename the method to `asideSection`.

Here is how I would write it, also following the [ruby style guide convention](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide) of using `snake_case` for variables and method names:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :get_aside_sections

  def home
    # ...
  end

  private

  def get_aside_sections
    @aside_sections = Page.all
  end
end
```